# nginx serve static files over both https and http

Tags: http, nginx, configuration, https, static

So, I want to secure only the login and admin part of my website. The problem is that the admin uses some common static files that are used on the general site as well. This means that when I am in the admin those files should be served over ***https*** while when I am on the general site they should be served as ***http***.

How can I configure nginx to behave this way?

The configuration I use so far is bellow:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/site_folder/web;
    index index.php;

    location ~ /(get-involved|contribute|api) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/site_folder/web/index.php;
    }

    location / {
        root /home/site_folder/web;

        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php last;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate path_to_ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key path_to_key.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/site_folder/web;
    index index.php;

    location ~ /(get-involved|contribute|api) {
        root /home/site_folder/web;

        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires max;
            break;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/site_folder/web/index.php;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear. Nginx doesn't choose how to serve file. It's browser that choose which protocol to use (really it's written in html usually)

Comment: hey @AlexeyTen thanks so far. I have added the configuration I use. The problem is that under `https` in `/contribute` the static files (js, css) come under `http`. Also when I come back from secure to non-secure section the static files are also not loaded.

Comment: You have redirect from https to http. Don't do it for static files.

Comment: Where do you keep your static files?

Comment: the static files are here: `/home/site_folder/web`

Comment: Did you find a solution?